# Using Ajax helpers Versus using regular html with jQuery code

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor, ajax.beginform

I am a fan of using Ajax helpers inside my asp.net mvc web applications. I used `Ajax.BeginForm` and `Ajax.Actonlink` frequently.
But I recently came across a more standard and more maintainable way to manage my forms and links.
So instead of writing something such as :-

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("Show Servers", "CustomerServer","Customer",
    new {customerID = Model.AccountDefinition.ORG_ID},
    new AjaxOptions {
 InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
 UpdateTargetId = "detail"  ,
 LoadingElementId = "progress",

 OnSuccess="detailsuccess",



}
)
```

I can define a regular `<a>` and define its target url as follows:-

```
<a data-modal='' href="@Url.Action("CustomerServer","Customer", new {customerID = Model.AccountDefinition.ORG_ID})"   title='GetListCustomer'>  Show Servers</a>
```

And then to define a javascript as the following, that will take the role of the Ajax helpers. It will perform similar calls to the `Ajax.ActionLink` & also when a form is being submitted it will perform a similar call that is being generated by `Ajax.Beginform` using the   `bindForm(this);` function, as follows :-

```
  $(document).on('click', 'a[data-modal]', function (e){
            $('#myModalContent').css({ "max-height": screen.height * .82, "overflow-y": "auto" }).load(this.href, function () {
                $('#myModal').modal({
                    //code goes here..
                    handle: ".modal-header"
                });
                $('#myModalContent').removeData("validator");
                $('#myModalContent').removeData("unobtrusiveValidation");
                $.validator.unobtrusive.parse('#myModalContent');
                bindForm(this);
              $("input[data-autocomplete-source]").each(function () {
                  var target = $(this);
                    target.autocomplete({
                        source: target.attr("data-autocomplete-source"), minLength: 1, delay: 1000, appendTo: $("#myModal")



                   });

                });
            });
            return false;
        });


    });



    });
    function bindForm(dialog) {
        $('form', dialog).submit(function () {
            $('.btn.btn-primary,.btn.btn-danger').prop("disabled", "disabled");
            $('#progress').show();
            if ($(this).valid()) {

                $.ajax({
                   //code goes here


                                });

                            });
                        }
                    }
                });
            }

        });
    }
});
```

I found the second approach more standard and maintainable.  Especially because I do not have to hard code the ajax setting on each `ajax.actionlink` ; `InsertionMode`, `UpdateTargetId`, `OnSuccess="detailsuccess"`,etc on each ajax helper component.

So can anyone advise on the pros and cons of using these two approaches?

Comment: This really depends on what are you tring to achieve.

Comment: A little code here, a little code there.  Either way you do it you can achieve your desired results.  Many times it comes down to developer preferences.

Comment: @adricadar sorry but i did not get your answer... i need to have ajax links and ajax forms, also in-case the user have javaScript disabled to perform regular calls . where the two approaches will support this ... so what i want to achieve is the same using the two approaches ,, can you adivce more on this please?

Comment: @Dean.DePue but generally speaking having all the control inside one javascript is consider more power full and more maintainable comparing to hard coding the ajax settings on each ajax helper components ?

Answer (score 2):

I asked myself more or less the same thing. Then I stumbled over a very interesting *Microsoft Jump Start* video about [Developing ASP.NET MVC 4 Web Applications](https://www.microsoftvirtualacademy.com/en-US/training-courses/developing-asp-net-mvc-4-web-applications-jump-start-8239).

Take a look at the chapter **Developing ASP.NET MVC Views**. You will find the answer in the Lesson 2: Using HTML Helpers.

---

As they explain in the video, ActionLink understands routing, it understands your model and generates automatically the right url if you change you're routing. UrlAction does not, it just creates the url you specified in your code.

By the way that's the real advantage of all html-helpers. They are built-in and know about what's going on with your application.

Comment: Probably because you provided [a link](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/113437/answering-questions-with-links-to-other-answers-on-stackoverflow) to an answer rather than an answer.

Comment: @greenhoorn yes you are 100% correct, html.actionlink and ajax.actionlink will generate the url based on the routing system.. but in my case my routing system will not be changed very frequent , or maybe will not be changed at all,, so in this case this is not a real advantage in my case, but you are correct I forgot this important point ..

Comment: @johnG In this case I would say there is no advantage and no disadvantage. So it's your decision what you want to use. I would recommend you to follow the KISS principle, Keep It Small and Simple. If customizing is the way to do so, do it.

Comment: @greenhoorn so which approach is consider KISS compatible ,, using AJAX helpers or using standard html with custom jQuery code ?

Comment: This depends completely on your application. Since you're saying the standard html with custom jQuery code is more maintainable I assume it's simpler ;) Take a look at your application and decide, which way is better for now and more important for your future application.

Comment: @greenhoorn but i think there is a URL helper that generates the url based on the routing system,, which is UrlHelper.HttpRouteUrl. so i can use it instead of URL.Action and have my generated links based on the routing system..

Comment: I downvoted as it wasn't an answer at the time. Edited version is fine. :)